# Are there any cases of a word that originated in English replacing another word in English in common usage?

Tags: etymology, history

I'm curious if there's any cases of a word that originated in English (didn't come from a foreign source) replacing another word in every day usage?

Comment: Do you mean a word that originated in English and that replaced another word that originated in a foreign language?

Comment: Both foreign and native origin for the original word would be fine.

Comment: In Middle English, the verb [*need*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=need) replaced the verb *tharf*. Both from Old English, and we certainly don't use *tharf* anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One example: Old English *lið* has been replaced by *limb*, both of native origin. [This Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changes_to_Old_English_vocabulary) has a bunch of such examples of obsolete words, though most of the replacement words are from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Something like *thou*? *You* is the form which has replaced the archaic *thou*.

Comment: Not so.  Thou remains the second person singular-familiar.  You is the second person formal or plural.

Comment: Thou remains? What kind of archaic dialect do you speak?

Comment: I, personally, do not use "thou" in ordinary speech. Members of my father's family still use it, just within the family. "What thinkest thou?" They are/were Friends (Quakers) and the family came from Yorkshire. "You" may have replaced "ye", "thou" has a separate use.

Answer (score 2):

The word *withershins* is rarely used anymore, it is the same as *counter-clockwise* or *anti-clockwise*, both with Latinate origin, both still English words.

Comment: More commonly spelled [widdershins](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/widdershins), when it does appear...

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., *doughnut* (first OED citation 1809) replaced the Dutch-origin word *olykoek* (first OED citation 1795). For *olykoek*, a 1740 calque [translation] *oily cake* is cited, so the word *olykoek* may have been in use well before *doughnut*.

This first OED citation for *doughnut* is

> D. Knickerbocker, *Hist. N.Y.*  An enormous dish of balls of sweetened dough, fried in hog's fat, and called doughnuts, or olykoeks.